# Configure angular 8 to run behind proxy

Tags: angular, routes

I am attempting to configure a livereload angular 8 dev app (started with ng serve...) to run behind an nginx proxy. e.g mydomain.com/app1

I'm running this stackblitz example locally:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-routing-with-modules-with-bootstrap?embed=1&file=src/index.html
```

here is my local version:

```
https://angular.syntapse.co.uk/nested-module/
```

I have set the baseHref and deployUrl in angular.json and added  in the index.html

my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name angular.syntapse.co.uk;
     location /nested-module/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3601/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
```

my index.html  includes

```
  <head>
    <base href="/nested-modules">
    <title>Angular Router</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
```

my root angular.json config includes baseHref and deployUrls.

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/demo",
        "baseHref": "/nested-modules/",
        "deployUrl": "/nested-modules/",
```

On loading the app into chrome the assets URL's look correct but they aren't being loaded - 404 error. There are no errors on the server.

I am unsure what additional changes I need to make beyond deployUrl and baseHref to load assets for an nginx proxied angular app.

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple solution enables live hot module reloading for one or more applications running from a single domain. --public-host needs to point to webpack default sockjs url (default used here is /sockjs-node)

nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    location /first-app/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3601/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
     location ^~ /first-app/sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3601/sockjs-node/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
     location /second-app/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3602/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
    location ^~ /second-app/sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3602/sockjs-node/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

Angular package.json conf (repeat per angular app):

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3601 --disable-host-check --public-host https://yourdomain.com/first-module/sockjs-node/",
```